# Conditional statement with 3 variables in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a better way to write a function in Vue.js like this conditional statement below, this works for 2 conditions:

```
    {
        accessToken:
          process.env.NODE_ENV == "production"
            ? "ZkIEqD1i8FVF628krYkPhAtt"
            : "nroV5bOcaS2CHUosOINLJgtt",
        cacheProvider: "memory"
      }
```

But, if I need to add a third, I am not sure how to do this, this is not working:

```
      {
         accessToken:
           process.env.NODE_ENV == 
             "staging" ? "TY8ljH8FVyeYAfX0F7Qkfwttstaging"
             : "production" ? "ZkIEqD1i8FVF628krYkPhAtt"
             : "nroV5bOcaS2CHUosOINLJgtt",
         cacheProvider: "memory"
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply add a third check, i would suggest you to add a switch case instead which will be more cleaner in your case.

but for the above question here is your answer

```
       accessToken:
         process.env.NODE_ENV == "production"
           ? "ZkIEqD1i8FVF628krYkPhAtt"
           : process.env.NODE_ENV == "staging"?"ZkIEqD1i8FVF628krYkPhAtt":"nroV5bOcaS2CHUosOINLJgtt":  "nroV5bOcaS2CHUosOINLJgtt",
       cacheProvider: "memory"
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a helper function to do this job...

```
function decideFor<K, T>(value: K, options: [condition: K, value: T][]): T | undefined {
  return new Map(options).get(value);
}

const options = {
  accessToken: decideFor(process.env.NODE_ENV, [
    ['staging', 'TY8ljH8FVyeYAfX0F7Qkfwttstaging'],
    ['production', 'ZkIEqD1i8FVF628krYkPhAtt'],
    ['developement', 'nroV5bOcaS2CHUosOINLJgtt'],
  ]) || 'invalid NODE_ENV',
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On such cases I prefer the approach of using a lookup table to map your keys to specific values.

```
const defaultAccessToken = "nroV5bOcaS2CHUosOINLJgtt";
const envs = {
  production: "ZkIEqD1i8FVF628krYkPhAtt",
  staging: "TY8ljH8FVyeYAfX0F7Qkfwttstaging",
}
const y = {
  accessToken: envs[process.env.NODE_ENV] || defaultAccessToken
}
```